# Расположение Box элементов по вертикали (flex?)

Tags: html, css

Необходимо расположить элементы необычным образом (как показано на рисунке), ширина блоков задана `width:50%`, пытался сделать через `flex`, но что-то не как не пойму как это сделать, возможно ли это сделать через css?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

**Важно**: блоки могут быть различной высоты.

Расположены должны быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как Вы пытались сделать через flex? Покажите css

Comment: а просто вывести элементы в порядке 1-4. 2-5. 3-6 нельзя?

Comment: @Confireus свет отключили, хотел добавить не успел))) ахах, как только включат скину.

Comment: @teran количество элементов может быть разным

Comment: и чего что разным? колонки 2 если, дак надо разделить количество на 2 получив середину m, и брать 1:m+1, 2:m+2

Comment: @teran суть в том, что есть два вида отображения, условно "большая" и "маленькая", на "большой" все BOX идут по порядку друг под другом и width:100%, на маленькой как на рисунке. поэтому и спрашивал про css, да бы не писать костыли на JS

Comment: @AlexKnow: т.е. условия для "маленькой" таковы:  две колонки, всегда один и тот же порядок блоков, независимо от их высоты. Так? А если 1-2-3 будут содержать минимум контента, а 4-5-6 - максимум, то как это должно выглядеть? Должны ли нижние блоки добивать высоту или это не нужно.

Comment: да, не ясно. всегда будет две колонки по полам,  или надо оптимально разместить контент, что получится первая например 1-2-3-4 (маленькие блоки) а вторая 5-6 (много контента)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужен никакой флекс:

```css
.wrapper {
  /* you need this: */
  column-count: 2;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
  /* and you need this: */
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1<br><br><br></div>
  <div class="box">2<br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class="box">3<br><br></div>
  <div class="box">4<br></div>
  <div class="box">5<br><br><br></div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задай wrapper высоту height чтобы помещались 3 блока, затем используй свойство flex-direction: column и flex-wrap: wrap. Если нет, то нужно пробовать другие способы

Comment: количество элементов и высота блоков могут быть различными.

Answer (score 0):

Для `display: block;` и `display: inline-block;` существует такое правило как [`column-count`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/column-count).
Но вроде как это колхоз..

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 2;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.wrapper .box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, свет отключили, как только включат попробую)

Comment: к сожаления не подходит, высота блоков может быть разной, обновил картинку

Answer (score 0):

Обязательно ли каждый 2 блок должен быть чуть больше первого?
Работает внезависимости от количества элементов.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid Black;  
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: это классно, такого раньше не видел, но высота блоков может быть разной, обновил картинку.